# What is the difference between and.stub vs and.callFake in Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am a newbie to `Jasmine` and a bit confused between above two functions. My sole purpose is to give a fake implementation to a spy function. But, If I put debugger in `callFake` the it is getting called but `and.stub`'s function is not getting called. Could anyone please explain what is the difference between these two functions.

```
spyOn(manager, 'getUsers').and.stub(function () {
    //to do
});
```

vs

```
 spyOn(manager, 'getUsers').and.callFake(function () {
        //to do
    });
```

Comment: One of the things to note is your example passes a function to the `stub()` method; however, there is no method signature for stub that accepts a parameter. That is the first hint.

Answer (score 20):

Looking at the documentation located at https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies, when you `spyOn` something it logs of all the calls being made on the spied on object method. This means that it is calling the actual method of the object, but keeping track of what calls were made.

If you want to allow using the original object, but don't want specific methods to be called, you have the options of using `and.callFake` and `and.stub`. The differences are in the method signatures.

---

`callFake` takes a function as a parameter. This allows you to fake the method call and return the value you desire.

original method signature is `myMethod(param1: string): string`

```
spyOn(service, 'myMethod').and.callFake((param1) => {
    expect(param1).toBe('value');
    return 'returnValue';
});
```

---

`stub` has no parameters and merely intercepts the call to the method

```
spyOn(service, 'myMethod').and.stub();
```

myMethod can have parameters and can have a return type, but it doesn't matter since stub just intercepts the call and will return `null` if there is a return type.

---

In both instances, the method calls are logged and you can then do something like `expect(service.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalled()` or `expect(service.myMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith('value')`

Answer (score 0):

So, `let mySpy = spyOn(service, 'myMethod').and.stub()` is the exact same as `let mySpy = spyOn(service, 'myMethod')`. Both of these do the same 2 things:

1 - they will wait until that function is called and can report back on it later and tell you if it was called via `expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled()`.

2 - they intercept the function and NEVER call it. So if you spy on a function, it doesn't actually get called. Which is extremely useful when paired with `let mySpy = spyOn(service, 'myMethod').and.returnValue(someUsefulReturnValue)`.

However, as a side note, in some situations you want to spy on a function to see if it was called, write an expectation that it was called, BUT actually allow it to get called, which is when you would use `let mySpy = spyOn(service, 'myMethod').and.callThrough()`

Whereas, `let mySpy = spyOn(service, 'myMethod').and.callFake()` does the same 2 things in the bullet points above, except with one benefit. You can call a function inside of `callFake()` that will execute inside of `myMethod`. I find this is not extremely useful when following programming principles, and is used less often.

I.e. `let mySpy = spyOn(service, 'myMethod').and.callFake(() => { this.somethingThatNeedsToBeUpdated = somethingUseful; })`